# Trouble Capturing URLs With Campaign Tracking Parameters in Redshift

Tags: regex, posix, amazon-redshift

I am trying to capture URLs that have tracking parameters in a query to a website's homepage. There are cases where the parameter can have a forward slash before the query begins. Here are two examples that should match:

```
https://test.com/?utm_campaign=email
https://test.com?utm_campaign=email
```

Here are two examples that should not match:

```
 https://test.com/blog
 https://test.com/blog?utm_campaign=email
```

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT t.url,COUNT(t.id) AS pageviews
FROM db.table AS t
WHERE t.url ~ '^https*:\\/\\/test\\.com\\?'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Note that Redshift documentation states:

> To search for strings that include metacharacters, such as ‘. * | ? ‘,
>   and so on, escape the character using two backslashes (' \\ ')

I have tried both single and double slashes. The single slash returns a lot more than I expect, whereas the double slash does not return any results. I'm more accustomed to writing regex in Javascript, and as such I assume I'm having trouble translating between the two; any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try `'^https?://test[.]com[?]'`. No need to escape `/`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew '^https?://test[.]com/[?]' worked...thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` symbol is not a special regex metacharacter, you should not escape it. Besides, in order to avoid issues with escaping `.` or `?`, you may put them into bracket expressions:

```
WHERE t.url ~ '^https?://test[.]com[?]'
```

It will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `https?://test[.]com[?]` - `http://test.com?` or `https://test.com?`.